# Obtaining keyword for matching string in Python

Tags: python, string, text-files, glob

I am writing a script that searches through text files in a directory for certain words. If "True" is returned, then it will print the text file it found it in. Is there a way to return/print the keyword it actually found? Thank you!

```
from glob import glob

def main():
    directory = "C:\\Files Folder\\*.txt"
    filelist = glob(directory)
    keywords = ("Hello", "Goodbye", "fake")
    for textfile in filelist:
        f = open(textfile, 'r')
        for line in f:
            if any(s in line for s in keywords):
                print "Keyword Found!", f.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in f:
    for s in keywords:
         if s in line:
            print 'Key word found!', f.name, s
```

Comment: Thank you, Very simple solution. What I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help, Shankar.

Answer (score 0):

Not with that. You will have to expand the `any()` call into a `for` loop in order to get the specific keyword found.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use:

```
for line in logfile:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in KEYWORDS:
            print word
```

Comment: `line.split` is unnecessary and will slow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I think a small modification of you code is enough

```
from glob import glob

def main():
    directory = "C:\\Files Folder\\*.txt"
    filelist = glob(directory)
    keywords = ("Hello", "Goodbye", "fake")
    for textfile in filelist:
        f = open(textfile, 'r')
        for line in f:
            for keyword in keywords:
                if line.find(keyword)>0 :
                    print "Keyword Found!",keyword, f.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```